# Not-found page does not work in next.js 13

Tags: next.js, next.js13

This is the sturcure of my next.js project.

[image]

And my 404.js page is :

```
'use client';

export default function NotFound() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Not Found</h2>
        </div>
    );
}
```

when I enter the wrong route it does not work and does not go to my custom page and goes to next.js **404** page.
why, Where am I wrong?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) to see how you can improve your question.

Answer (score 61):

With Next 13.3 you just need to change the file name to `not-found.js`.

An `app/not-found.js` file will now automatically handle visits to an URL that does not have a matching route in your app.

Docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/not-found

Announced in : https://nextjs.org/blog/next-13-3

---

With Next 13.2, according to the [docs](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/file-conventions/not-found):

> "Note: not-found.js currently only renders when triggered by the notFound function, we're working on support for catching unmatched routes."

So it's not yet automatic but looks like they are working on it. File should also be named `not-found.js` instead of `404.js`,

In the meantime, as it looks like dynamic routes are resolved after static routes, you can solve it by creating a [dynamic catch-all route](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/defining-routes#catch-all-segments) using a `[...not_found]` folder and add it to your app folder.

[image: Image of folder structure for a Next 13 application showing the app folder with a [...not_found] folder, an articles folder and a layout.js, not-found.js, and page.js file in the root of the app folder.]

Inside the dynamic route folder add a `page.js` file that calls the `notFound()` function.

**app/[...not_found]/page.js**

```
import {notFound} from "next/navigation"

export default function NotFoundCatchAll() {
  notFound()
}
```

And inside the `not-found.js` file in the root of your app folder you can add your custom 404 page.

**app/not-found.js**

```
import Link from 'next/link'

export default function NotFound() {
  return <div>
      <h1>Not found – 404!</h1>
      <div>
        <Link href="/">Go back to Home</Link>
      </div>
  </div>
}
```

Important to note that this approach can create problems if you have  multiple dynamic routes in your app folder. Dynamic routes in another static folder should be fine however.

Hope it helps and good luck!

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) to see how you can improve your answer.

Comment: Is it possible to explicitly navigate to the `src/app/not-found.js`? Like by going to `app.com/not-found`? What I'm trying to do is use the custom server and specifically render the not-found page. The `render404` doesn't appear to work.

Comment: I have this setup correctly, yet my 404 template is missing all styles. The Layout template is being inherited, but all of my styles are missing. Any thoughts on how to diagnose this?

Comment: This seems to be still needed in nextjs 14, if anyone is wondering. Also in my case, the "catch all" did not work to redirect me to any `not-found.js`.

Comment: Same here, in NextJS 14 the "catch all" does not redirect to the root not-found.tsx.

Comment: @Vacilando @Caranown Assuming you migrated from a SPA with react-router-dom and wrapped it into a [[...slug]] catch all, the reason is that nextjs will let react-router handle the redirects for all other routes that are not defined by the folder route system. in this case i used `import { notFound } from 'next/navigation'`and `notFound()`instead of the `<Redirect to={appRoutes.notFound} />`where in the old react-router code i handled the error redirects to hand it over to nextjs again

Answer (score 5):

NextJS13 doesnt do error handling in this format, you dont want to use a file named `404.js` but instead a file named `error.js`.

This will catch any errors sent from an API request returning a 404 response.

Docs here: https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/error-handling

---

If your API instead returns a 200 response but an empty body, you could create another component named `not-found.js`, import that into the file you want it to show on, and return it on if the api is empty, for example:

**app/dashboard/not-found.js**

```
export default function NotFound() {
  return (
    <>
      <h2>Not Found</h2>
      <p>Could not find requested resource</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

**app/dashboard/index.js:**

```
import { notFound } from 'next/navigation';

async function fetchUsers(id) {
  const res = await fetch('https://...');
  if (!res.ok) return undefined;
  return res.json();
}

export default async function Profile({ params }) {
  const user = await fetchUser(params.id);

  if (!user) {
    notFound();
  }

  // ...
}
```

Docs here: https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/notfound

Comment: Is it possible to explicitly navigate to the `src/app/not-found.js`? Like by going to `app.com/not-found`? What I'm trying to do is use the custom server and specifically render the not-found page. The `render404` doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 2):

Create a directory labeled `[404]`, and within it, place the `page.{tsx/jsx/js}` file as usual. You're all set!

Comment: This is actually a reasonable option.

If you want to return the proper HTTP code 404, you could create [404].page.ts with this content:
```
import { notFound } from "next/navigation";

export default function Page() {
  notFound();
}
```

And then create a not-found.tsx in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

As @Fredrik Carlsson said

> With Next 13.3 you just need to change the file name to not-found.js

While this applies to 13.3 and up, I still couldn't get it to work. Instead, I kept getting this issue:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: NEXT_NOT_FOUND at notFound
```

Turns out that the issue is due to me using `'use client'` at the top of my file. After removing that line, my `not-found.js` file works correctly.

If you're curious about **structure and how I'm specifying my not-found file**, I've got:

- One file in `/app/not-found.js` which handles any invalid routes in root `/`
- And another in `/app/blog/[slug]/not-found.js` which handles any invalid routes in blog `/blog`

If you're curious about **how I'm triggering the not-found function**:

```
// app/blog/[slug]/page.js

async function getBlogPost(slug) {
  const blogPost = await client.fetch('https://example.com/...')

  if (!blogPost) {
    notFound() // <-- this triggers this the nearest not-found.js file
  }
  return blogPost
}

const BlogPost = async ({params}) => {
  const slug = params.slug
  const post = await getBlogPost(slug)

  return <Post post={post} />
}

export default BlogPost
```

**References**

- https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/not-found
- https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/not-found

Answer (score 0):

For video reference in codeGrepper => https://www.grepper.com/answers/723464/Not-found+page+does+not+work+in+next.js+13?ucard=1

//src\app\not-found.tsx

```
export default function NotFound() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Page not found</h2>
      <p>Are you lost?</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

for overall website you can use not-found.tsx or jsx in root of app folder

app\products[productId]\reviews[reviewId]\page.tsx

for seperate dynamic not found page use notFound function from next/navigation
we can also create seperate 404 page for each route segment making seperate not-found.tsx
here below we display that

```
import { notFound } from "next/navigation";

export default function ReviewDetail({
  params,
}: {
  params: { productId: string; reviewId: string };
}) {
  if (parseInt(params.reviewId) > 1000) {
    notFound();
  }  

  return (
    <h1>
      Review {params.reviewId} for product {params.productId}{" "}
    </h1>
  );
}
```

//src\app\products[productId]\reviews[reviewId]\not-found.tsx

```
export default function NotFound() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Review not found cannot be greater then 1000 id</h2>
    </div>
  );       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change file name to not-found.js or if you're using type script change file name to not-found.tsx.

Answer (score -8):

To create a not-found page in Next.js using the app folder, you can follow these steps:

1. Create a new folder named pages in your project's root directory.
2. In the pages folder, create a new file named 404.js.
3. In the 404.js file, add the following code to render the Not Found page:

   ```
   const NotFound = () => {
     return (
       <div>
         <h1>404 - Not Found</h1>
       </div>
     )
   }

   export default NotFound
   ```
4. In your _app.js file, add a catch-all route to display the Not Found page for any unknown routes:

```js
import App, { Container } from 'next/app'

class MyApp extends App {
  static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
    let pageProps = {}

    if (Component.getInitialProps) {
      pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
    }

    return { pageProps }
  }

  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props

    return (
      <Container>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Container>
    )
  }
}

export default MyApp
```

Now, when a user visits a route that does not exist in your application, the Not Found page will be displayed.

Comment: This is a great answer for nextjs 12 and below. The user wants NextJS13 which uses the new React Server Components in the new `/app` folder and not the `/pages` folder.