# Custom 404 error page inside route segment

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

I have a custom 404 error page (= not-found.tsx) file. Actually two, one within `app/(paths)` and one within `app/(paths)/(jobs)/jobs/(cats)`. The first not-found file should render when a user goes to url example `myapp.com/blablabla-nothing-here`. The second not-found file should render when a user goes to url example `myapp.com/jobs/blabla-no-job-cat-here`. In both these cases my custom not-found file does not render. Why?
Here my full structure:

[image: full_structure_folders_files]

P.S. The content of my `not-found` file is correct, because when I move it to `app/not-found` then it renders. The "global" one that is. The "local" inside /jobs does not.

Moving files around and expected it to work but it did not.

Comment: maybe try the dynamic catch-all route in the answer on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75302340/not-found-page-does-not-work-in-next-js-13